# GDB Server and GDB Client who sends the "+" first?

Tags: gdb

GDB Client:

NetworkClientConnect 503: Attempting host: 10.23.37.155 (addr: 02CE4B50)

NetworkClientConnect 518: Connected to host: 10.23.37.155

NetworkClientRecv 576: **Recv Packet: +**

NetworkClientSend 550: Sent Packet: +

GDB Server:

Debug: 243 275 pld.c:207 handle_pld_init_command(): Initializing PLDs...

Info : 244 22937 server.c:83 add_connection(): accepting 'gdb' connection from 3333

Debug: 247 22954 gdb_server.c:260 gdb_get_char_inner(): **received '+'**

Debug: 248 22954 gdb_server.c:272 gdb_get_char_inner(): returned char '+' (0x2b)

Initially the connections are made then they acknowledge that they got the packet by sending "+". In my case the client says it is receiving a '+' and so does the server as the very first info exchange. That does not make sense. One has to send and the other receive what I see is both receiving and sending in parallel. But it is working. So where is my thinking wrong? Also if you can point me to a URL which shows exactly the GDB Server and Client protocol exchange that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

In your GDB client printout, it looks to me, messages are not printed in order (see that Recv packet has number 576, and sent 550).

Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or similar tool to debug an issue like this.

I tried connecting to gdbserver via loopback and according to wireshark the dialogue looks like this:

1. client sends "+"
2. client sends "$qSupported:multiprocess+;xmlRegisters=i386;qRelocInsn+#b5"
3. server sends "+"
4. server sends "$PacketSize=3fff;QPassSignals+;..."

and so on.

Gdb does help an option selectable at runtime that can help debug such things. Start it, then issue "set debug remote 1". Same on remote side. Start gdbserver by "gdbserver --remote-debug ...". This will print remote gdb protocol dialogue on both sides.

Another, possibly best if most time consuming options is to check the gdb&gdbserver source.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I also thought of lagged dispaly. 576 and 550 are program line numbers. However Wireshark was a good advice. I have installed it. How do I configure it to read packets between 2 IP's? All I need is the first 25 packets. I have Wireshark 1.82 running on Windows. If you know how to do it please advice. Thanks again

Comment: Don't worry I figured out the WireShark. I shall debug this and then answer my own question later.

Comment: Glad it was useful. Although this is probably a workaround. gdb and gdbserver are open source, so one could check there (but this is probably time consuming). There is another helpful option I forgot about. I updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I got into WireShark Help Forum (http://ask.wireshark.org/) and posed the question there. "How to capture packets between 2 IP's". There a person called Quadratic gave a brilliant answer. You can refer the WireShark site or here it is. It works like a charm!!

Do this:
•   When you first start Wireshark, click on the button in the far upper-left that says "List the available capture interfaces" when you scroll over it.
•   In the new "Capture Interfaces" window that opens, select the interface you want to capture packets (with the check box on the left-hand side) and click"Options".
•   In the Capture Options window, on the lower-left corner there should be a "Stop Capture Automatically After..." seciton. Check the "packets" option and put in a value of 50
•   In the same Capture Options window, in the text box to the right of "Capture Filter", type the statement (without quotes) "ip host 10.xx.xx.xx and ip host 10.yy.yy.yy".
•   Hit the Start button :)
One small thing to note - if the interface you're capturing is doing vlan tagging, replace the capture filter statement to "vlan and ip host 10.xx.xx.xx and ip host 10.yy.yy.yy" without quotes.
Edit:
An even simpler solution is to just use one command line statement:
C:\Program Files\Wireshark\dumpcap.exe -c 50 -i {interface name or number} -w {wherever you want to save the packet capture file}

Comment: This is not a question on how to capture packets between two IPs.